# Click on Growl with link

Tags: jsf, primefaces, growl

I'm using jsf and Primefaces and I need some help.
I built in my project a IdleMonitor. It will trigger after the timeout a growl and I want to build in a clickable link. But my problem is that I can't add html code into the bean and didn't find anything about actions after clicking on the growl.

[image]

```
    public void onActive() {

      String link = "<a href=\"http://abcd.efg.com\" target=\"_blank\">http://abcd.efg.com</a>";

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Deine Session ist abgelaufen", link));
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
        <prime:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" redisplay="false" escape="false"/>
                <prime:idleMonitor timeout="5000">
                    <prime:ajax event="idle" listener="#{idleMonitorView.onActive}" update="messages" />
                    <prime:ajax event="active" listener="#{idleMonitorView.onActive}" update="messages"/>
                </prime:idleMonitor>         
    </h:form>
```

Comment: looks like `escape="false"` does not work. Old PF version? Tried without sticky? and redisplay? or showDetail

Comment: it works without redisplay but then 2 growls from the exact message appear. Weirdly only the first one can handle the html code and the second one is like the one in the screenshot.